# INSERT com ON CONFLICT UPDATE dando erro ["ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "aj"]

Tags: postgresql, tabela-banco-de-dados, sql-update, sql-insert

[Print de como ficou tudo com 20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9ITM.png)
[Os valores que deveria replicar na tabela (diversos)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqtnp.png)

Tentando inserir dados da tabela AJUSTE para a tabela FATURA_ASSINANTE, e quando não tiver o id da tabela AJUSTE na tabela FATURA_ASSINANTE, que seja inserido, caso contrário somente o update, como mostra abaixo:

```sql
insert
    into 
    fatura_assinante (cod_assinante,
    cod_plano,
    valor_faturado)
select
    aj.cod_assinante,
    aj.cod_plano,
    aj.novo_valor
from
    ajuste aj
on
    conflict (cod_assinante) do
update
set
    fatura_assinante.cod_assinante = aj.cod_assinante,
        fatura_assinante.cod_plano = aj.cod_plano,
        fatura_assinante.valor_faturado = aj.novo_valor;
```

Alguém poderia ajudar a resolver?

Comment: Por qué sua query está dentro de un div?

Comment: saiu sem querer

Comment: A imagem está distinta do código colado como texto. É melhor corrigir a sua pergunta.